# Examining the prime and maximal ideal of $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a given ring assigned by $R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$.
Let us consider the ideal $I$ of $R$ which is given by $I=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}:b,c \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$. 
Prove that $I$ is a prime ideal as well as a maximal ideal of $R$.

I am trying to show it by observing that $R/I$ is an integral domain. Let us take any elements $M_1$ and $M_2$ from $R/I$. Then if $M_1M_2$ belongs to $I$ under matrix multiplication, then it is easily observed that one of $M_1$, $M_2$ must be in $I$, which gives us the integral domain prove of $R/I$. Is my way of proceeding is in correct way?
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: you should include your attempt. people prefer to treat those who have attempted their question more positively.  tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh. Sir I have edited my question , that what i have think to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map

$$R \to \mathbb Z, \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix} \mapsto a.$$

Check that this is a ring homomorphism (basically you have to check that if you multiply two matrices of $R$, then their diagonal elements are multiplied).

It is clearly surjective and its kernel is $I$, hence $R/I \cong \mathbb Z$.

In particular $I$ is not maximal, because the kernel of $R \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a larger ideal.